# Query JSON column with array of objects MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have the following json array in my column:

```
[  
   {  
      "day": 1,
      "requests": 23
   },
   {  
      "day": 2,
      "requests": 5
   },
   {  
      "day": 2,
      "requests": 9
   }
]
```

and I want the row that has day `1`. I already tried to do it with

```
SELECT * FROM api WHERE usages->'$[*].day' = JSON_ARRAY(1)
```

but it returns no results.

Comment: Try  [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd976ca71ef3a44b55710f417dbfe314).

Comment: @wchiquito You should post it as answer

Comment: Thanks @LukaszSzozda, but Schwern's answer includes my proposal.

Comment: @wchiquito At point where I wrote that answer Schwern's answer was deleted. You could check it using https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52130389/revisions. Anyway good job and keep going :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select usages->'$[*].day' from api` shows that it's the JSON array `[1,2,2]`.

`where usages->'$[*].day' = JSON_ARRAY(1)` is trying to match `[1,2,2]` with `[1]` which isn't true.

Instead, use [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) to look for values within the array.

`where json_contains(usages->'$[*].day', "1");`

Comment: How is `[1,2,2]` equal to 1? `where usages->'$[*].day' = 1.` This query returns 0 rows. [Counterexample demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7b32ec9e5ef9852d993cdd8ea4aef45)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Whoops. Had to install MySQL to remember how their JSON works.